# ViewPager not working on Google Glass KitKat [XE16]

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-glass, android-4.4-kitkat

Google Glass Gets Updated With KitKat [XE16] today. I have developed one application with **viewPager** which was working fine with XE12. But after updating  to KitKat[XE16] viewPager not working on the glass.

Searched for the **change-log** and **release note** for the **KitKat** for **Google Glass developer**. I got the [features release note](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/4578099).

Now I need to know two things.

1. Is ViewPager deprecated in Google Glass KitKat[XE16]?
2. Is there have any release note or change-log for XE16 for google glass developer?

Comment: Got the [Google Glass KitKat XE16 Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Is ViewPager deprecated in Google Glass KitKat[XE16]?

   Kind of. ViewPager isn't explicitly deprecated in XE16, but it was never actually a fully supported. If you have cards of content that you'd like to flip around, use [CardScrollView](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView) instead. You can learn more about using it in [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets#scrolling_cards_in_immersions).
2. Is there have any release note or change-log for XE16 for google glass developer?

   Yup! Check out the [Glass platform release notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes#xe16).